# I am trying to open a gnuplot through command line using c++ and compile a graph

Tags: c++, cmd, gnuplot, popen

My code is

```
int gnuplot() {

    FILE *gnu;
    gnu = _popen(" gnuplot ", "r");

    fprintf(gnu, "plot \'C:/Users/user/Documents/gnuplot/cpp/FFT/file.dat\' with linespoints \n ");

    fflush(gnu); // I'm not sure how or if this will help, I thought it was related

    _pclose(gnu);

     return 0;
}
```

At the moment I am able to just open the CMD window of the gunplot window but not enter the plot command or exit it.

Comment: Just to let you know. There is a gnuplot C++ interface available [here](https://github.com/orbitcowboy/gnuplot-cpp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gnu = _popen(" gnuplot ", "r");
```

It should be write mode instead.

```
gnu = _popen("gnuplot ", "w");
```

Comment: Sorry I whould have added that I tried that already. 
If I change "r" to "w" it opens it and closes it quickly, barely noticeble. 
same if I remove the line _pclose(gnu);. how can I make it close the cmd but keep the gnuplot window open?

Comment: One approach: plot to image file, so you don't need to keep the gnuplot window open

Comment: Another approach: Use `system("gnuplot -e \"plot \'C:/Users/user/Documents/gnuplot/cpp/FFT/file.dat\' with linespoints\"");` instead of popen.

Comment: This is my code now, it yields me gnuplot is not recognized and no files created.



FILE *gnuopener;

 gnuopener = _popen(" gnuplot ", "w");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "plot \'C:/Users/yes/Documents/gnuplot/cpp/FFT/jesus.dat\'  with linespoints\n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "set term postscript\n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "set output \"jesus.ps\" \n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "replot\n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "set term png\n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "set output \"jesus.png\" \n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "replot\n");

 fprintf(gnuopener, "set term win \n");

 _pclose(gnuopener);